# Make a range of radian values in Python

Tags: python, function, math, range, trigonometry

I have an equation (integrand) and want the for loop to produce an array of values that can then be plotted. Both the variables in the integrand function are the arguments of cosine. math.cos only allows radian values so I want my range to be from 0 to 90 degrees (pi/2 radians) but the range function does not allow float values. How can I achieve this. My attempt, but doesn't work because of the float issue is:

```
for i in range(0, 0.5*(math.pi), 0.0174533):
    yvalues = integrand(i, 60)
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this do it for you?  Let **i** be the measure in degrees

```
for i in range(90):
    yvalues = integrand(i * math.pi/180, 60)
```

If you want the whole array at once, use a comprehension:

```
yyvalues = [integrand(i * math.pi/180, 60) for i in range(90)]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're serious about math and arrays of numbers, definitely check out [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and avoid the loop in your code altogether:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> yvalues = integrand(numpy.linspace(0,numpy.pi/2,361), 60) 

>>> print(numpy.linspace(0,numpy.pi/2,17))
[ 0.          0.09817477  0.19634954  0.29452431  0.39269908  0.49087385
  0.58904862  0.68722339  0.78539816  0.88357293  0.9817477   1.07992247
  1.17809725  1.27627202  1.37444679  1.47262156  1.57079633]]
```

This may require editing the `integrand` function, but getting to use numpy arrays instead of python lists can make code more readable and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Go by degrees, and convert to radians:

```
for i in range(0, 90):
    radian = i * 0.0174533
    yValue += integrand(i, 60)
```

You could also do it in a single line with list comprehensions:

```
yValue = [integrand(i * 0.0174533, 60) for i in range(0, 90)]
```